# Reference generated primary key in SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I'm trying to create a bunch of entries in a database with a single script and the problem I'm encountering is how to reference the generated primary key of the previous entry I created.

For example if I created a customer, then tried to create an order for that customer, how do I get the primary key generated for the customer?

I'm using SQLServer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
DECLARE @customerid int;
INSERT INTO customers(name) VALUES('Spencer');
SET @customerid = @@IDENTITY;
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently it needs to be SCOPE_IDENTITY() in order to function as expected with triggers.

```
DECLARE @customerid int;
INSERT INTO customers(name) VALUES('Spencer');
SET @customerid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: I believe scope_identity() is preferred to @@IDENTITY in most situations.

Comment: +1 for Joels note, scoped_identity will handle triggers gracefully (eg. if you have an insert trigger, your @@identity can become bogus)

Comment: That did the trick thanks, I'm using SQLServer 2005 which does seem to support scope_identity().

Comment: Kenny, scope_identity() is supported by SQLServer 2005 and even 2000. It is safer to use than @@identity.

Answer (score 4):

If available in your version, use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead.  Safer than @@IDENTITY.

Answer (score 2):

If you are inserting multiple rows at once, you can get all the identities (for use in, say, creating related records) by using the `OUTPUT INTO` [feature of SQL Server 2005 or later](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-output-clause-to-capture-identity-values-on-multi-row-inserts).

This could avoid you having to write loops and cursors etc.